# Looking for a "selective" design pattern to avoid if-elses

Tags: design-patterns

I have the following CSV entries:

```
2014-05-19 02:33:36,590,MGW,5147014,3056260212,ONNET,IN,CALL,95
2014-05-19 02:33:37,139,MGW,8827533,923049586878,ONNET,IN,NONCALL,95

2014-05-19 02:33:36,989,MGW,5463607,bbb063414604620,OMO,IN,CALL,95
2014-05-19 02:33:37,789,MGW,2677011,92bbb033368524299,OMO,IN,NONCALL,95

2014-05-19 02:33:38,750,MGW,8754053,OUT,ATI-REQ
2014-05-19 02:33:36,788,MGW,7652136,IN,ATI-RES,assumedIdle,0

2014-05-19 11:07:29,743,MGW,73011143,03636895,REDIRECTED,IN,CALL,95,92300142

2014-05-19 02:37:18,405,MGW,6313475,IN,ALERTSC
2014-05-19 02:07:02,507,MGW,6870068,IN,Report-RES
2014-05-19 02:07:02,710,MGW,7835732,OUT,Report-REQ
```

My algorithm to insert these records in the database would work like this:

```
if col[4] == "REDIRECTED"
//insert the 3rd column in 5th field in db
else if col.length > 7 and col[7] == "CALL"
//insert it without any change
else if col[5] == "ALERTSC" || "Report-REQ" || "Report-RES"
//insert all these with a common replacement of fields
else ignore all the rest
```

**Question**
I want to have a pattern by which:

1. I pass on this entry to all the classes and whichever one has its concern with the record processes it,
2. If no class is there to match the record, the record gets ignored

**The Factory pattern**

The Factory pattern would have been the choice had the row discriminator been on the same column, by which the conveyer would have identified the product by the same column. But here the identifier is at different places so how does the distributor/conveyer send the row to its respective handler/factory?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why cannot you give the full row to the factory and let it decide?

Comment: You may use the Chain of Responsibility pattern. http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Answer (score 0):

Using different classes to carry out the same task with different algorithms is the Strategy pattern, but the Gang of Four's original definition of the Strategy pattern doesn't deal with selecting strategies. That comes up all the time and I'd handle it like this:

Write a class -- let's call it a `Creator` -- for each type of CSV line with a method `create!` that checks to see if the line matches the class's type, parses the line (maybe a superclass will be helpful here), saves the entry in the database and returns it. If the `Creator` doesn't match the line, `create!` just returns nil.

Then, in the "conveyer":

```
lines.each do |line|
  [RedirectedCreator, CallCreator, AlertCreator].each |creator|
    if creator.new.create! line
      break
    end
  end
end
```

If the process of saving the entry to the database isn't specific to the type of line, you could have your strategy classes just parse the line and return a parsed form, and let the caller do the saving in one place.

Another variant of this pattern is for the strategy class to have a method `accepts?` that takes the item to be worked on and returns true or false without actually doing anything to it, and a second method that actually does the work.