# Design pattern to transform one type of data to another

Tags: design-patterns

I have to call a legacy SOAP webservice that sends a raw [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), from a clean(er) REST webservice that sends data described in JSON.

I need to transform this raw dataset that lists my objects into a true list of objects.

The dataset I get does not have enough informations, so the transformation is not "simple". It involves fetching additional data from the DB for each object.

What's the best design pattern to do this? My first naive reflex would be to create a method that takes this dataset as parameter, parses it, and returns a list of objects, but I feel there must be a better way of doing this.

I have seen the Adapter pattern, but I understand it "only" transforms an existing class into another that "looks like it". I want to completely change the data, from something akin to a table of strings with the id and name, into a true collection of instances with every useful info.

## Update

I have another, similar problem coming up. We have both an old desktop application, and a new online application doing the same things, but in different ways. The save file for these two applications is very different, though.
I would like to create a convertor between these formats. The Mapper pattern, as suggested by @VS1 looks promising for this operation, but I don't think I would be able to use something as simple and straight-forward as AutoMapper. The Adapter pattern may also be of help. I'll look into these.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783355/looking-for-a-selective-design-pattern-to-avoid-if-elses

Comment: Why do you think you need something more complicated than a single function? Do you need or foresee a need of multiple converters? with dependencies between them? Should a converter be selected in runtime? Updated in runtime?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth : that's a very interesting idea, but I don't think it answers my problem here. I'll keep it in mind, though.

Comment: @AndyT : I'm really not sure. It's more a feel like "it could be more elegant, but how?".

Comment: @AndyT: actually I just thought of another use case for this. I'll update the post with more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to either build a kind of `Mapper` on your own, that transforms your `Dataset` to `objects`; or you can use available tools such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

These mappings require the knowledge of [Adapter](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) and [Builder](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) design patterns in general. I would emphasize more torwards *Builder* pattern to be more important in building this mapping.

You could also use `LINQ` and `Extension Methods` to achieve your requirement as per [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/195889/Convert-Datatable-to-Collection-using-Generic).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it answers my problem. I will look into these infos.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of "patterns" come to mind for this type of work:

1. [Serialization/Deserialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization): I put patterns in quotes since I don't think this really counts as a pattern, but it puts a proper name to what you're trying to accomplish. Hopefully this make it easier to search for help/resources. There are plenty of existing libraries meant to serialize between JSON, SOAP (XML), and objects (what languages are you using?). These often make use of attributes on classes to help the proper transformation, leaving only a small amount of code to do the actual translation.
2. [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern): If you already have the serialization part down, and you can actually return objects from your legacy service, you could use the Facade Pattern to wrap the old object with a new one that better maps to your new service. For example, if your new service objects need to implement a different interface:

```
SoapServiceObject sso = OldService.Get();
IRestServiceObject rso = new RestServiceObjectFacade(sso);

public class SoapServiceObject
{
    public string name;
}

public class RestServiceObjectFacade : IRestServiceObject
{
    private SoapServiceObject _sso;

    public string IRestServiceObject.Title { get { return this._sso.name; } }

    public RestServiceObjectFacade(SoapServiceObject sso)
    {
        this._sso = sso;
    }
}
```