# Removing conditional code as part of Strategy pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have some code which performs different logic depending on a conditional. But using strategy pattern does not allow to remove conditional code? Using Google this seems to be a common consequence of using the Strategy pattern : https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=removing%20if%20statements%20strategy%20pattern

For example :

```
class Cond {
 if(cond1){
  perform1
 }
 if(cond2){
  perform1
 }
}
```

Strategy pattern :

```
interface Performer {
   doWork
}

class Perform1 implements Performer {
  doWork
}

class Perform2 implements Performer {
  doWork
}

class Cond {
 if(cond1){
  new Perform1.doWork
 }
 if(cond2){
  new Perform2.doWork
 }
}
```

Strategy pattern is more concerned with open-closed principle than actually removing conditional code ? Also isn't conditional code a natural occurrence of programming ?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783355/looking-for-a-selective-design-pattern-to-avoid-if-elses/23784621

Comment: This is a refactoring, not strategy. http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, conditionals are a fundamental and inherent element of programming. You cannot, nor is there any reason to want to, "remove conditional code" from any non-trivial program. There are different ways of *implementing* conditional code, and there are situations where some are preferable over others, but this notion of removing it entirely is, frankly, nonsense.

The strategy pattern is simply about encapsulation - specifically, it's about encapsulating algorithms: Look at the difference between the two examples you gave. You *haven't* removed any conditionals, the same two `if` statements are there in both examples. The only difference is that, in the latter, you have encapsulated your algorithms in classes .

Answer (score 1):

The Strategy pattern only encapsulates differences, you still need to assign the correct behavior during the execution.

You might attach the strategy to the object requesting the work instead of setting the condition flag.

Have a look here on how to convert a switch with polymorphism: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

This just doesn't quite look to me like a strategy pattern implementation.  I understand it's pseudo-code, but I just don't follow it.  This example is more straightforward, and does in fact remove the need to write conditionals when executing the strategy:

```
// Strategy Interface
public interface CompressionStrategy {
    public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files);
}

public class ZipCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
    public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
        // using ZIP approach
    }
}

public class RarCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
    public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
        // using RAR approach
    }
}

public class CompressionContext {
    private CompressionStrategy strategy;

    // this can be set at runtime by the application preferences
    public void setCompressionStrategy(CompressionStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    // use the strategy
    public void createArchive(ArrayList<File> files) {
        strategy.compressFiles(files); // <-- with stragtegy set, notice that 
                                       // no conditionals are required here.
    }
}

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          CompressionContext ctx = new CompressionContext(); 
         //we could assume context is already set by preferences 
          ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new ZipCompressionStrategy());     
         //get a list of files 
        ...
         ctx.createArchive(fileList);    
       }
}
```

Comment: how do you determine the type of compression strategy ? Some conditional logic will need to be determined at some point even if it is within preferences ?

Comment: This doesn't look like the strategy pattern, just polymorphism. The point of the Strategy is to let the context decide on the strategy. If you're choosing the strategy manually, you are just using an object.

Comment: You're right.  I deleted my last comment.  This would not have much value if you could only set the strategy manually prior to runtime.  Hence, the above code supports setting the strategy at runtime using the setCompressionStrategy() function.

Comment: Just to clarify this. Strategy is not about letting context decide on the strategy. The context is just decoupled from algorithm's implementation. Apparently, it's okay for the context to set the strategy itself, but saying that it's about just that, is wrong. Check the following quote from GoF book on strategy:
> "A context forwards requests from its clients to its strategy. Clients usually create and pass a ConcreteStrategy object to the context; thereafter, clients interact with the context exclusively. There is often a family of ConcreteStrategy classes for a client to choose from."

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something similar to a chain of responsibility (c# sorry)

```
interface Performer {
    bool CanHandle(/* criteria/lambda */);
    void DoWork();
 }

 class Cond
 {
    void Do()
    {
         Performer strategy=strategies.Find(s=>s.CanHandle(/* condition */));
         if (strategy==null) throw new NoStrategyAvailable();
         strategy.DoWork();

     }
 }
```

Maybe not the purest Strategy pattern applied, however it's quite maintainable: if you use reflection to get all the strategies from the project, you just add a new strategy implementation and it just works.